# Turn-based game map in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a turn-based game in python and I have some problems with game map.
This is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, SURF):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.SURF = SURF

    def createNewMap(self, D1, D2):
```

create a D1xD2 map

```
        self.Map = []
        self.D1 = D1
        self.D2 = D2
        for n in range(self.D1):
            current = ['']*self.D2
            self.Map.append(current)
        return self.Map

    def drawMap(self):
```

draw the D1xD2 map from (x,y) position. grass.gif represent 1 grass box. the map contain D1xD2 grass boxes.

```
        imgObj = pygame.image.load('images\\textures\grass.gif')
        imgObj = pygame.transform.scale(imgObj, (40, 40))
        xc = self.x
        yc = self.y

        for itemY in self.Map:
            for itemX in self.Map[self.Map.index(itemY)]:
                self.SURF.blit(imgObj, (xc, yc))
                xc += 40
            yc += 40
            xc = self.x
```

i want when the mouse is above a box, i want to changes it with another texture box(grass1.gif). how can i do this?

Comment: You're naming things confusingly. How does `Map().createNewMap()` make any sense? `Map()` already means "create a new map" - is that not what it's doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by getting the current mouse position and then checking whether that is in the bounds of the box. Here is an **unrelated** example:

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for rectange in my_objects_list:
    if rectangle.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        #do something ...
```

Comment: i have much boxes. is another way to do this without make all boxes Rectangles and after check each? won't this will be to slow?

Comment: @user3451666, I will updated my answer to address your new question. Just a minute.

Comment: @user3451666, It may seem intensive but won't even be a problem for the computer. Answer updated.